# wildfly classloader issue between war's lib and ear's lib

Tags: java, classloader, wildfly, ear

I've this schema for an EAR deployed in Wildfly:

- EAR:

  - ejbA.jar
  - ejbB.jar
  - lib

    - LibInterfaceA.jar
    - LibInterfaceB.jar
  - WAR

    - lib

      - LibInterfaceA.jar

LibInterfaceA.jar is a library of only interfaces used in ejb modules (A adn B) and in WAR for injecting ejb and extended in LibInterfaceB.jar .

The problem is with java reflection when I search for custom annotations inside LibInterfaceA:

```
public Annotation getAnnotazione(Method method, Class annotationType){
    Annotation annotazioni[] = method.getAnnotations();
    URL locationsearch = annotationType.getResource('/' + annotationType.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
    for(Annotation a : annotazioni){
        Class klass = a.annotationType();
        URL location = klass.getResource('/' + klass.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
        if(a.annotationType().getName().equals(annotationType.getName())){
            return a;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I call this method in a class inside the WAR to find the annotation *annotationType=@Custom*. @Custom is of WAR/lib/LibInterfaceA.jar

If i call this method to find on a Class implementing a LibInterfaceB's interface that extends an interface in LibInterfeceA, the annotation @Custom on the method is of the jar EAR/lib/LibInterfaceA.jar , so the classes are different for classloading problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. Are the two LibinterfaceA.jar's the same just in two different locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove LibInterfaceA.jar from war. By default sub deployments of ear can use its lib directory (unless you set ear-subdeployments-isolated = true in jboss-depoyment-structure.xml of ear)

Comment: Resolved marking the dependency in war as <scope>provided</scope>, so the library is included only ad EAR level